# Plotting Issues with utf8 encoding

Tags: python, utf-8

I am attempting to take several 2D plots of Magnitude vs. Frequency as a function of x and y positions, then introduce a third axis to be able to show y-dependency. However, **the simple 2D plot I have is not matching the data**, and **I have to assume that it is due to the fact that the data is utf8 encoded.**

Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import glob, os
import codecs
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------                   
os.chdir('C:/Users/elarrick/Desktop/201807161056')
dataFolders = glob.glob('./*.ltda')

dataLines = []
freq = []
OpenLoopMag = []
OpenLoopPhase = []
for item in dataFolders:
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(item)
    if ext == '.ltda':
        print item
        dataLines = []
        f = codecs.open(item, encoding='utf-8')
        for line in f:
            if '<p>' in line:
                dataLines.append(line)      #All lines with <p> are an entry in dataLines
        #print "\n\n", dataLines
        #break
        for item in dataLines:
            item = re.sub("<p>", "", item)
            item = re.sub("True</p>", "", item)
            item = item.replace(",", "")
            splitItem = item.split()
            #print splitItem
            freq.append(splitItem[0])
            OpenLoopMag.append(splitItem[1])
            OpenLoopPhase.append(splitItem[2])
        print "Frequencies: ", freq
        print "\n\n\n\n\n\nOpenLoopMag: ", OpenLoopMag
#   This is where I will make the plots for each x,y position
        name = name.strip(".\\")
        name = name.replace("-","NEG")
        #plt.semilogx(freq, OpenLoopMag)
        plt.plot(freq, OpenLoopMag)
        plt.xlabel("Frequency, (Hz)")
        plt.ylabel("Magnitude")
        plt.title("{0}".format(name))
        #plt.xlim([20,2000])
        #plt.ylim([-43.2,10.9])
        #ticks = [20,40,70,100,200,400,700,1000,2000]
        #plt.xticks(ticks,ticks)
        plt.savefig("plot_{0}.png".format(name))

#________ Clear the values for the next data folder_______#            
        freq = []
        OpenLoopMag = []
        OpenLoopPhase = []
        break
    else:
        print "Something went wrong - check ColorMap.py"
        sys.exit()
```

The values (just a few for the sake of example) I have for `freq` and `OpenLoopMag` are:

```
Frequencies:  [u'20', u'20.2321728649916', u'20.4670409419452', u'20.7046355186148', u'20.944988245963', u'21.188131142377', u'21.4340965979342', ..., u'1977.04914182566', u'2000']


OpenLoopMag:  [u'10.9797774776683', u'9.40509858861171', u'8.38037523081066', u'7.84390252022723', u'7.36930058248386', u'6.97548426230449', u'6.59941431608661', ..., u'-42.4773549086419', u'-37.3733298906582']
```

**Thus, the scale of the y-axis should be ~10.** However, when I plot them, the result looks as shown (**Note:** The reason the y-axis looks so bad is because **the result is all 8 digit numbers** of which I cannot determine the scale):

[image: Semilog Plot]

I have no idea why my data for `freq` and `OpenLoopMag` do not match up, but the upper plot in the following picture is the desired output:

[image: Actual Data]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know matplotlib, but shouldn't you be converting those number strings into actual numbers, eg floats?

Comment: You're probably right - I hadn't done it previously because it allowed me to plot, but it could be that the numbers being plotted are the numerical representations of the data...